# Safari пишет "Сертификат устарел", но сертификат действует

Tags: javascript, safari

У меня небольшой сервис JavaScript скрипт которого устанавливается на сайты клиентов. Это скрипт встраивает готовые формы на сайты клиентов.

Во всех браузерах нормально работает, а в Safari выдает "действия сертификата сервера истек." естественно он не выполняет работу свою, хотя сертификат стоит и стоит правильно (vk иначе бы не работал с ним) годен еще год.

**Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой? Решали как-то?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновлять браузер пробовали?

Comment: Сложно что-то говорить про сертификат если вы не показываете адрес сайта

Comment: Safari 5.1 версия для винды (может в этом дело). Но у людей походу тоже чет тупит. Да сертификат в норме уверяю, мне бы VK API не работало если бы что-то было не так...

Comment: Скорее всего Ваш сертификат подписан/выдан центром сертификации, которому не доверяет или не знает Сафари. Вариант номер два - битый мак (при условии, что это единичный случай)

Comment: Пробовал сертификат покупной COMODO, пробовал 
Let’s Encrypt бесплатный один и тот же результат.

Comment: Тогда скорее всего кто то просто удалил часть корневых сертификатов в маке. Либо мак старенький и без обновок. Конечно, не исключаю каких то странных настроек (например, время в будущем)